# Отразить положительные элементы из верхней полуплоскости зеркально в нижнюю

Tags: python, матрицы

Как положительные элементы из верхней полуплоскости отразить зеркально в нижнюю?

Код на питоне:

```
from random import*
B = [[randint(-20,25) for j in range(11)] for i in range(6)]

for i in range ( len(B) ):
    for j in range ( len(B[i]) ):
        print ( "{:5d}".format(B[i][j]), end = "" )
    print ()

for i in range( 6):
    for j in range (11):
        if i == j:
            if B[i][j] > 0:
```

Comment: А как математически выглядит отражение полуплоскости для индексов? Вот подумайте, выведите простую формулу, и примените.

Answer (score 1):

Если верхом у вас считается первый столбец, то вам нужно развернуть задом наперед каждый вложенный массив. Если первая строка - то развернуть массив массивов. Чтобы развернуть массив, надо пройти по нему до середины и поменять каждый iый элемент с iым элементом с конца. Скорее всего в синтаксисе питона есть какая-нибудь конструкция или встроенная функция, которая это умеет

Comment: Вы случайно строки со столбцами не путаете?

Comment: Это зависит не от меня, а от от содержимого строк со столбцами и контекста таблицы. Если вы посмотрите на матрицу с идеально круглыми нулями, вырезанную из своей книжки - вы тоже перепутаете с вероятностью .5